# RecyclerView ListAdapter with Header View

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, listadapter, android-diffutils, android-listadapter

It seems ListAdapter with `AsyncDifferConfig` and `DiffUtil` does not work properly when a RecyclerView has header itemview implemetation, the list always start to display items at bottom upon calling `submitList()`. Is there a way to use ListAdapter with header itemview? This is the only possible [solution](https://medium.com/brightec-ideas/extending-the-listadapter-with-a-header-view-ceeffe03f929) that I saw upon researching and it seems that very little is known on this issue. Is there other way or standard way that Android provides to solve this problem?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Please let me know if you have figured it out

Comment: @hushed_voice you can use `ConcatAdapter` instead